# Is permission stored permanently for geolocation HTML 5?

Tags: html, geolocation

When a user visits the website, we ask for his permission using getCurrentPosition. And, if the user gives the permission, we use the coordinates to get his position. Now, I don't want this prompt to happen every-time user comes on my site. Is there an API call which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is browser dependent. Most browsers will store the preference for each individual site. You have no control - there is no API you can use to get the browser to remember the user's preference.